# Difference between find() and findWhere in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I use find for :

```
 find("from domain d where d.id=? AND d.name=?",[params.id, params.name])
```

that gives me first matching result.
Now I see there is findWhere() for :

```
  Book.findWhere(author: params.author, title: params.title)
```

Also returns first matching result set.
What is the basic difference and when to use either.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's also `Book.findByAuthorAndTitle( params.author, params.title )`

Comment: @tim_yates So you mean all 3 of them are same?

Comment: Added an answer with my results for this simple example (using Grails 2.3.7)

Comment: @tim_yates Thank you so much for your efforts. This explains it all!

Comment: No worries, tested it with Author being a separate domain class, and the results are the same :-) I tend to prefer `findByAuthorAndTitle`, but this can get unwieldy for many parameters, so then I tend to fall back to a criteria based query.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Right, so I created a test app, created a test Domain class:

```
package test

class Book {
    String title
    String author

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Added some dummy data in the Bootstrap:

```
import test.*

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        new Book( title:'Book 1', author:'Tim' ).save()
        new Book( title:'Book 2', author:'Alice' ).save()
        new Book( title:'Book 3', author:'Bob' ).save()
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

And a test controller:

```
package test

import grails.converters.JSON

class BookController {
    def test1() {
        Book b = Book.find( "from Book as b where b.author = ? and b.title = ?", [ 'Tim', 'Book 1' ] ) 
        render b as JSON
    }
    def test2() {
        Book b = Book.findWhere( author:'Tim', title:'Book 1' ) 
        render b as JSON
    }
    def test3() {
        Book b = Book.findByAuthorAndTitle( 'Tim', 'Book 1' ) 
        render b as JSON
    }
}
```

Then, turned on hibernate logging by adding

```
trace 'org.hibernate.type'
debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'
```

to the log4j section of Config, and:

```
logSql = true
```

To the `dataSource` section of DataSource.groovy.

Then, ran all 3 controller methods.

`find` executes:

```
select book0_.id as id0_,
       book0_.version as version0_,
       book0_.author as author0_,
       book0_.title as title0_
from book book0_
where book0_.author=? and book0_.title=? limit ?
```

`findWhere` executes:

```
select this_.id as id0_0_,
       this_.version as version0_0_,
       this_.author as author0_0_,
       this_.title as title0_0_
from book this_
where (this_.author=? and this_.title=?) limit ?
```

And `findByAuthorAndTitle` gives us:

```
select this_.id as id0_0_,
       this_.version as version0_0_,
       this_.author as author0_0_,
       this_.title as title0_0_
from book this_
where this_.author=? and this_.title=? limit ?
```

So as you can see, in this simplistic example they are just 3 ways of saying the same thing